# ES6 array destructuring for specific index

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an Array `const arr = new Array(100)`.

And I set

```
arr[0] = 'A'
arr[49] = 'X'
```

When destructuring the 1st element, I can do it like:

```
let [first] = arr
```

How the statement would be like if I want to access to the 50th element by destructuring expression?

Comment: It would best be `let x = arr[49]`

Comment: @bambam He's talking about destructuring

Comment: I know, but you wouldn't use destructuring to get the 50th element @NullDev

Comment: Please note it's *destruct**ur**ing*, not *destructing*.

Comment: And if he asked you to jump off a cliff...

Comment: @bambam What if it's an interview question? It certainly is possible to do it in JS. You can always suggest to use arr[50] as side note in your answer.

Comment: @connexo yea, `destructuring` (I typed it two times :) thanks)

Comment: I ran into the issue because ESLint notifies me to use destructuring while I am going to use `let key = arr[3]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can grab the element using object destructuring, like so:

```js
const arr = Array(50).fill(0).map((_, i) => `Element ${i + 1}`)

const {49: fifty} = arr
console.log(fifty)
```

Comment: can the index by dynamic?

Comment: @capr Can you be more specific? Destructuring like this isn't common, just use bracket notation like `arr[index]`.